Color detection Problem for Brighter colors
I made a algorithm for color detection. Basically, what it does it extracts the main colors of a clothing item. the main issue I'm having is that the model is having issue detecting color outside of blue:
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
the algorithm use for color clustering is the Peter Hansen method.
I will apricate if anybody has a recommendation for this model on how to get more accurate responds for brighter colors
the algorithm I'm using for the retrieval of color names is the following:
def closest_color(requested_color):
    TOP_COLORS = {
    'black': (0, 0, 0),
    'white': (255, 255, 255),
    'red': (0, 0, 255),
    'blue': (255, 0, 0),
    'green': (0, 128, 0),
    'yellow': (0, 255, 255),
    'orange': (0, 165, 255),
    'pink': (203, 192, 255),
    'purple': (128, 0, 128),
    'brown': (42, 42, 165),
    'gray': (128, 128, 128),
    'navy': (128, 0, 0),
    'lime': (0, 255, 0),
    'fuchsia': (255, 0, 255),
    'silver': (192, 192, 192),
    'gold': (0, 215, 255),
    'khaki': (140, 230, 240),
    'turquoise': (208, 224, 64),
    'violet': (238, 130, 238),
    'indigo': (130, 0, 75),
    'coral': (80, 127, 255),
    'chocolate': (30, 105, 210),
    'darkblue': (139, 0, 0),
    'darkcyan': (139, 139, 0),
    'darkgreen': (0, 100, 0),
    'darkred': (0, 0, 139),
    'midnightblue': (112, 25, 25),
    'lightblue': (230, 216, 173),
    'lightgreen': (144, 238, 144),
    'lightgray': (211, 211, 211),
    'lightpink': (193, 182, 255),
    'lightyellow': (224, 255, 255),
    }

    min_distance = float('inf')
    closest_color_name = None
    for color_name, rgb in TOP_COLORS.items():
        distance = np.sqrt((rgb[0] - requested_color[0]) ** 2 +
                           (rgb[1] - requested_color[1]) ** 2 +
                           (rgb[2] - requested_color[2]) ** 2)
        if distance < min_distance:
            min_distance = distance
            closest_color_name = color_name

    return closest_color_name


You could try to use HSV values instead of RGB. If this doesnt help you may want to tweak your distance calculation such that a change in "hue" creates greater distances than a change in "lightness" for example. Maybe this helps...
